# A form of the Gaussian integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Consider the function $f(x,y)=ye^{-(1+x^{2})y^{2}}$ if $x\geq0$ and $y\geq0$ and $0$ otherwise. Integrate this function over $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$ to show that $\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x^{2}}\,dx=\sqrt{\pi}/2$.

Here is what I have done:

\begin{align*}
   \int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}f(x,y)\,dy\,dx&=\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}ye^{-(1+x^{2})y^{2}}\,dy\,dx\\
   &=\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2}e^{-(1+x^{2})u}\,du\,dx\qquad(\text{set}\ u=y^{2},\ du=2y\,dy)\\
   &=\int_{0}^{\infty}\left[-\frac{1}{2(1+x^{2})}e^{-(1+x^{2})u}\right]_{0}^{\infty}\,dy\\
   &=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2(1+x^{2})}\,dx\\
   &=\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1+x^{2}}\,dx\\
   &=\frac{1}{2}[\arctan x]_{0}^{\infty}\\
   &=\frac{\pi}{4}
  \end{align*}

Now clearly the square root of $\pi/4$ will give the solution, but where does the $e^{-x^{2}}$ come in? Is there a way to break up the original integrand? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write
$$
\int_0^{\infty} \int_0^{\infty} f(x,y)dydx = \int_0^{\infty}\int_0^{\infty} ye^{-y^2}e^{-x^2y^2}dydx
$$
By Fubini-Tonelli,
$$
= \int_0^{\infty} \int_0^{\infty} e^{-x^2y^2}ye^{-y^2}dxdy 
$$
and substitute $u = xy$ to get
$$
\int_0^{\infty}\int_0^{\infty}e^{-u^2}e^{-y^2}dudy = \left( \int_0^{\infty} e^{-z^2}\right)^2
$$

Comment: Thanks for your response. Just one more thing, what are you referring to as $z$ here?

Comment: Either $u$ or $y$. I just edited my post - the use of Fubini-Tonelli should be mentioned here.